# jquery autocomplete combox not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete combo-box plugin in my form this work fine in all the browser except IE.

[this code I am using](https://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/fsRn4/4/)

When I focus or type it populate option but when I select it does not set selected option in input box. this works fine in other browser firefox and chrome.

Please help me if I missed anything here.

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.